Image in static directory didn't appear with Thymeleaf
So I'm using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf to display images. The code was:
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="width: 100%">
    <a class="navbar-brand" th:href="@{/image}" style="margin-left: 10%; font-weight: bolder">
        <img th:src="@{images/pipe.png}" width="20px" height="20px" alt="Logo">
        PipeCounter</a>
</nav>

The image pipe.png is put in resources/static/images directory, but the image didn't appear on the web. I checked the console and it showed the 404 error with a URL http://localhost:8080/images/pipe.png.
I also tried all the solutions from the other posts and the official website, but it still didn't work.

What happens if you change th:src="@{images/pipe.png}" to th:src="@{/images/pipe.png}"? In other words make the link use a context-relative path rather than a page-relative path. This may be one of the things you already tried when you "also tried all the solutions from the other posts", but we don't know because you haven't shared any of those details.

Another thing to test is: (a) src="images/pipe.png" and (b) src="/images/pipe.png" - i.e. don't place the path in a Thymeleaf link variable (just as a test). For reference: link URLs in Thymeleaf
